# How to push a local master branch to remote master branch?

Tags: gitlab

everyone.
I want to push all files in my local master branch to a remote master branch. but it doesn't work. I don't understand which process is wrong.

I am in the master branch and commit following:

```
git add -A
git commit - m "mycomment" 
//it returns "On branch maste Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'."

git push orign master:master
//it returns everything up-to-date.
```

But nothing has uploaded in my remote master.

Comment: I also tried git push -u origin master and git push. Doesn't work either

Comment: what is your git log and git status output?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` says?

Comment: I can't find the recent git push commit on the git log, My git status said "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'"

Comment: git remote -v shows the https address of my git rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if the remote repository already reflects your local files.
If that is the case, that means everything was already pushed.

If not, check if those files are ignored locally:

```
 git check-ignore -v -- aFileNotPushed
```

If it returns anything, that means a `.gitignore` or `exclude` file is actively preventing said file to be added/committed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a new branch from the master.  Pull this branch locally and build new codes on this branch. Then I can push successfully and merge into master. I am still confused about how to push to master directly. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks for the help.